# How to call a class member as a closure?

Tags: php, closures

I'm trying to make the following example works. It looks like PHP thinks `$this->getData2` as a member variable. How do I make it so that PHP thinks it as a method?

```
class Test {

    public function getData()
    {
        return array(
            'data1'=>array('name'=>'david'),
            'data2'=>$this->getData2
        );
    }

    public function getData2()
    {
        return "hello"
    }

}

$test = new Test;
$data = $test->getData();

$data = $data['data2']();
```

I've tried the following, but looks like..I can't use **$this** in this case

```
function() use($this) {
   return $This->getData2();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Test {

    public function getData(){
        return array(
            'data1'=>array('name'=>'david'),
            'data2'=>'getData2'
        );
    }

    public function getData2()    {
        return "hello";
    }

}

$test = new Test;
$data = $test->getData();

$data = $test->$data['data2']();

echo $data;
```

Wasn't working without the $test-> on the `$data = $test->$data['data2']();` line

And because I love fiddles:  http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/4f5-v37

Answer (score 2):

A callable to a method is an array with the object as a first member, and the method name as a second one.

So:

```
class Test {

    public function getData()
    {
        return array(
            'data1'=>array('name'=>'david'),
            'data2'=>array($this, 'getData2')
        );
    }

    public function getData2()
    {
        return "hello";
    }

}

$test = new Test;
$data = $test->getData();

$data = $data['data2']();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
class Test {
  public function getData(){
    return array('data1' => array('name' => 'david'), 'data2' => 'getData2');
  }
  public function getData2(){
    return 'hello';
  }
}
$test = new Test; $data = $test->getData(); echo $test->$data['data2']();
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would just be to do the calculation in a variable outside of the array and then just put the variable into the array